Finding the number of disjoint subset combinations
I am trying to solve a problem where the task is to find disjoint combinations out of two groups of subsets.
Consider a set $S$ of length $n$ with
$S=\left \{ 0,1,2, \dots ,n-1  \right \}$
and $n \equiv 0$ (mod $2,3$)
Then we have group $A$ containing all 2-element subsets of $S$, where the elements have a difference of $\frac{n}{2}$ with
$A = \left \{ 0,\frac{n}{2} \right \},\left \{ 1,\frac{n}{2}+1\right \},\left \{ 2,\frac{n}{2}+2 \right \},\dots,\left \{ \frac{n}{2}-1,n-1 \right \}$
And group $B$ containing all 3-element subsets of S with a difference of $\frac{n}{3}$ with
$B=\left \{ 0,\frac{n}{3},\frac{2n}{3} \right \},\left \{ 1,\frac{n}{3}+1,\frac{2n}{3}+1 \right \},\dots,\left \{ \frac{n}{3}-1,\frac{2n}{3}-1,n-1 \right \}$
E.g. with $n = 60$:
$S = \left\{0,1,2,\dots,59 \right\}$
$A = \left \{ 0,30 \right \},\left \{ 1,31 \right \},\left \{ 2,32 \right \},\dots,\left \{ 29,59 \right \}$
$B = \left \{ 0,20,40 \right \},\left \{ 1,21,41 \right \},\left \{ 2,22,42 \right \},\dots,\left \{ 19,39,59 \right \}$
Now given two numbers $a$ and $b$, I need to find the number of disjoint subset combinations (not the actual combinations) using $a$ sets out of $A$ and $b$ sets out of $B$.

You want a general formula, that works for all $a$, $b$, $n$? I think that's going to be quite difficult. For what it's worth, for $n=12$, I get, for $a=b=1$, $12$; for $a=2$, $b=1$, also $12$; for $a=1$, $b=2$, I get six.

Yes, I think it will be challenging... It seems to be somewhat related to the balancing centrifuge problem. I found this paper that gives some directions https://engrxiv.org/preprint/download/828/5131/3992

Can someone confirm $578716320$ for $n=60, a=9, b=5$?

Let's first study how the sets in $A$ and $B$ intersect each other. Let's draw a graph where we put edge if two sets intersect:

Now it happens that this graph is a disjoint sum of $\frac{n}{6}$ copies of $K_{2,3}$'s and there's an edge for each number $j \in \{0,1,\dots , n-1\}$.
Now, let's use inclusion-exclusion to count the asked quantity. Denote the space of all combinations by
$$
X = \{(U,V) \in \mathcal P (A)\times \mathcal P (B) : |U|=a, |V|=b\}
$$
Then we have the sets ($j = 0,1,\dots , n-1$ )
$$
F_j = \{(U,V) \in X :  j\in U\cap V  \}
$$
and we want to calculate the size of the complement of
$$
\bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} F_j.
$$
By inclusion-exclusion this is
$$
\large \sum_{J\subset [n]} (-1)^{|J|} \left |  \bigcap_{j\in J} F_j \right |.
$$
Now I don't know if there's a name for the following polynomial and a theorem concerning it but if, for a bipartite graph, we define the following polynomial: for all possible ways of choosing a subset $J$ of edges, sum the terms $(-1)^{|J|}x^u y^v$ where $u, v$ are the number of vertices (on parts) in the subgraph induced by the edges in $J$ (see example picture).

Then we can see that the polynomial for a disjoint union of two graphs is the product of the polynomials.
Now in this case we have (by brute-force calculation) the polynomial for $K_{2,3}$:
$$
p(x,y) = x^{3} y^{2} - 2 x^{3} y - 3 x^{2} y^{2} + 6 x^{2} y + 3 x y^{2} - 6 x y + 1.
$$
So we get the answer to the question as
$$
\large {\sum_{ cx^uy^v \text{ a term of } p^{\frac{n}{6}} }} c \binom{\frac{n}{2}-u}{a-u}   \binom{\frac{n}{3}-v}{b-v}.
$$
As Sage-code:
def f(n, a,b):
    R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 2)
    p1 = x^3*y^2 - 2*x^3*y - 3*x^2*y^2 + 6*x^2*y + 3*x*y^2 - 6*x*y + 1
    ret = 0
    for c,t in p1**(n/6):
        u = t.degree(x)
        v = t.degree(y)
        ret += c*binomial(n/2-u, a-u)*binomial(n/3-v,b-v)
    return ret


print (f(12, 1, 2))

